# Оценка производительности jvm

Tags: java, производительность, jvm

Тут вычитал штуку, что в случае использования не более 3х Гб heap, лучше использовать x86 версию JVM даже на 64-битной платформе.

Но я не знаю сколько реально памяти потребляется, кроме этого не знаю, насколько тогда выгодно ставить 32-х битную JVM. Говорят, что прирост производительности может достигать от 5 до 20%

Можно ли как-то померить потребляемую память и оценить ускорение ее работы при переходе на другую разрядность?

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если б "тут вычитал штуку" было ссылкой на то место, где вы эту штуку вычитали. Можно было бы оценить надёжность источника.

Answer (score 5):

Производительность вообще и производительность JVM в частности — сложная штука. Вот что производительнее, Windows или Linux? Это больше холиварный вопрос. Всё очень сильно зависит от сценариев использования, потребляемых ресурсов и так далее. Вас может волновать производительность при выполнении конкретной задачи, которая интересует конкретно вас. Можно легко поставить две JVM (32-бит и 64-бит) на одну машину и замерить время выполнения вашей задачи хоть секундомером.

Я думаю, что в большинстве случаев 64-битная JVM всё же окажется быстрее. Некоторые люди думают, что недостаток 64-битной JVM в том, что все указатели длиннее, поэтому будет больше рабочий набор (working-set), в кэш процессора поместится меньше полезных данных и так далее. Эти люди обычно не в курсе, что JVM (во всяком случае HotSpot) использует сжатые ссылки. Если вы используете до 4 Гб памяти в куче (задали опцию `-Xmx` со значением меньше 4 Гб), виртуальное адресное пространство выше 4 Гб не используется, и все указатели помещаются в 32 бита. Просто при загрузке в адресный регистр JVM загружает 32-бита, а старшие биты оставляет пустыми. Если вы выставили 4 Гб до 32 Гб, используется более хитрый режим, когда каждый указатель делится на 8 при сохранении в память (смещается на три бита), а при обращении по указателю назад распаковывается (тут используется то, что все объекты в куче выровнены по 8 байт, поэтому три младших бита в указателе на объект всегда нули). Это преобразование весьма быстрое. И только при использовании кучи больше 32 Гб включаются полноценные 64-битные указатели, и JVM реально начинает есть больше памяти.

Потребляемая память всё же увеличивается для 64-битной JVM, но не так значительно (в основном потому, что заголовок объекта может быть немного длиннее). Возможно, на некоторых специфических задачах этот прирост может оказаться критическим.

В 64-битном режиме доступно больше регистров процессора, поэтому больше данных JIT-компилятор способен раскидать в регистры. Это исключительно позитивно сказывается на производительности. Также совершенно точно будут гораздо быстрее все операции с типом `long`, потому что в 32-битном режиме под `long` используется два регистра и приходится в несколько инструкций выполнять сложения и умножения.

Наконец, я уверен, что в настоящее время 64-битную JVM гораздо больше тестируют и улучшают, в том числе в плане производительности, поэтому она в выгодном положении.

Comment: Всё правильно говоришь. Мой жирный +1 к тому, что чаще всего 64-битная JVM будет производительнее. Ещё из плюсов x64: согласно calling convention до шести аргументов методов передаются в регистрах, в то время как на x86 всё кладётся на стек. В x64 в одном из регистров всегда лежит текущий тред, на x86 получение треда - трудоёмкая операция. Из личного опыта - x64 менее стеснён в JIT оптимизациях, например, легко справляется с Common Subexpression Elimination там, где на x86 выражение вычисляется дважды.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте профайлер, например, встроенный: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\jvisualvm.exe`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]